# Is constant function a one-way function?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, cryptography

Is the constant function $\mathbb{X} \to 0, \forall \mathbb{X}$ a
[one-way function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function)? It seems:

1. computing the output is very easy and is computable in constant time;
2. given the output, the input is simply not possible to compute.

For simplicity, we can restrain $\mathbb{X}$ to be natural number, or the sets of strings of binary sequences etc.

Comment: (2) is not what the definition in your own link says. Note that the set of $x$ for which $f(F(f(x)))=f(x)$ will be all elements of $\mathbb{X}$. Therefore, you get the probability of that set equal to $1$ and $1$ will not satisfy the inequality $1<n^{-c}$ for all $n$ large.

Comment: Could you please expand and unpack those two functions a bit? I must've not understood that definition when I read it and still not quite.

Comment: From the quoted page (with the definition): "In particular, the function that outputs the string of n zeros on any input of length n is not a one-way function because it is easy to come up with an input that will result in the same output". So read the whole page before you ask a question on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No function with a limited number of values can be one-way, as even at best, if you have only $m$ values, the probability of guessing the outcome in case of uniform distribution is not less than $\frac{1}{m}$.

To be all harder would mean it needs a probability getting lower with all larger input.

In your case, guessing has a probability $1$ as you know the outcome.

One-way is not exactly reverting the function back, it is guessing which value will give this particular outcome. So it is *not* $f^{-1}$ it is $f(x_?)=Y$ where $Y$ is known and we try to guess or calculate $x_?$ not using $f^{-1}$ but in a specific sense *any* algorithm available, any program, any method, any theory that we know of or anyone will ever be able to know of.

In your case *any* input will give the same outcome so there is nothing to guess.

Comment: It is not about guessing a value, rather finding one. In this case, it is easy to find a preimage, just choose any.

Comment: @kelalaka: it **is** about guessing to some extent, which I did not want to elaborate in the text as we are looking for _polynomial time randomized algorithm_ $F$ otherwise you would not be able to talk about probability. I said in the text "guess or calculate" instead as it is simpler to understand.

Comment: @kelalaka: the simplest way to describe the difference between standard and randomized algorithm it is that a randomized algorithm can decide about the next step based on some predefined probability